# problem with onbeforeunload on IOS (Iphone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, dom

I have a page with this body :

```
<body>
    <div class="loading">
            <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-content">
            [... all the content]
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using this code to show / hide a spinner

```
function unLoader(e) {
    $(".site-content").hide();
    $(".loading").show();    
    }

$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".loading").hide();
    $(".site-content").show();
    window.onbeforeunload = unLoader;
     });
```

The problem is that the spinner works in desktop both PC and mac, on safari, firefox, chrome etc...

But it does not work on my Iphone.

On the other side, i am using the spinner for calls in ajax :

```
var $loading = $('.loading').hide();
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $loading.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
```

But this time the spinner works in mobile device (iphone) !

How can I make the spinner work for the mobile devices in all my pages (using the code shown first) ?

I know the problem is from `onbeforeunload` event

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1 : to answer the comment of josh, I even tried this :

```
var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
var eventNameHide = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";
var eventNameShow = isOnIOS ? "pageshow" : "load";

     $(window).on(eventNameShow, function(){
            $(".loading").hide();
            $(".site-content").show();
            window.addEventListener(eventNameHide, function(e) {
                $(".site-content").hide();
                $(".loading").show();    
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried the newer equivalent, `addEventListener('beforeunload', unLoader)`?

Comment: It's the native equivalent, and jQuery predates it.  So, yes, I'd say it's a "newer equivalent."

Comment: No one has any idea ? For information, even microsoft has this problem here :
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

No spinner on iphone, while a spinner on desktop ...

Answer (score 0):

beforeunload doesn't happen on iOS Safari. There is no event to bind actions to.